# software capacitor

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I need to use a software capacitor.

I have a signal with n samples. and i need to filter it.

Is there a c++ library(or a single function)  that contains a software capacitor and other electric components.

Comment: Do you need a low-pass/high-pass filter? If that's what you need consider using a C/C++ DSP library. If not and you want to model an arbitrary electric/electronic circuit then a _single function_ or a library won't be enough at all...

Comment: Voting to close as off topic because for single components (like a capacitor), the differential equations are well known (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor). For discrete filters, you're probably looking for something like an FIR filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response). For combinations of components, you're probably going to want something more like PSPICE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPICE), none of which is really that related to stackoverflow (maybe try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I want to model only capacitor. maybe other electric components later, but now, only capacitor. a "single function" or a "class" vould be enough...

Comment: Matlab or Octave is, also, for this purpose. I am trying to give basic algorithm , signal = vertical vector ( [N][1] ) starting from [1][1] ). Take all data store them in [1][N]. Then, send all vector to function whose job is filtering. To store data, use vector of double

Comment: @AndrewWalker :  "the differential equations are well known ". it is not what I am looking for. im lookin for a working C++ function or and algorithm. a filter is a problem for me because it causes a dely...

Comment: @eharvest the _problem_ is not if you want to model few capacitors or resistors. The point is **why** you have to do it. You want simply filter the signal? Check DSP SW. You want to simulate a (simple or not) electronic circuit? Go with a program for that, to do it by yourself isn't trivial and it's LONG.

Comment: @gcc : but how to filter (with no delay...) ?

Comment: @eharvest but a physical filter will delay your signal...

Comment: @Adriano : my problem is that i read a signal live. i need to "low pass filter it" but only with the past values and i dont wnt to have a delay... the electric capacitor can do this, so i wanted to use its principle. "dsp" : i need to have samples before and after the "sample i need to filter" and takes too much time.

Comment: @Adriano : not a capacitor. it is one reason to use it. the other reason is that i do not have the futur samples, only the past ones and i want to filter sample by sample.

Comment: @eharvest a filter made with a capacitor actually **will delay** your signal. Your "digital" filter will pop out "zero" for few samples (it depends on the filter order) then you'll get what you want. Moreover any filter (physical of digital) isn't a perfect model and at the beginning will be noisy (so you won't see "clean" signal for much more than the few samples of its delay...). As last: you **do not need future samples**. Take a look here on [MusicDSP.org](http://www.musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=3#185).

Comment: @Adriano : ok. I seems weird that a capacitor causes a delay, but i will search for this. thank you for the link. i will take a lok at the musicDsp library.

Comment: @eharvest It would take much more than an article on wikipedia but start to take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay. Of course they have different _types_ of delay but the result is the same. More important than the delay do not forget the initial transitory of the filter

Comment: @Adriano : the delay causes me a problem. i need to have the real position of a peak, not a delayed one. Of course I can calculate the deay of the filter which is constant despite change of frequency but in the cases i tested, the delay is not well found.

Comment: @eharvest phase shift is not constant for IIR filters, if you can't accept that approximation then you better move to (more complex) FIR filters; this is even worse than the initial delay (anyway you do **not need to measure** it, **you know** how many samples it is, just look the implementation of the filter and you'll see a "queue"). Anyway this may be a good question for a DSP group (I guess there is here on stackexchange too).

Comment: @Adriano : I have been told that butterborth have a fixed phase delay... maybe is that wrong...

Comment: @eharvest yes, it's not true. Butterworth filter has (just) a **more linear** phase response than other filters (like Chebyshev, for example) but it's **not fixed** (= the same for all frequencies) at all. (note: *phase delay* comes from filter *phase response*).

Comment: Another note: strictly speaking we should talk about *group delay* instead of *phase delay*. Take a look to the link I posted few comments ago.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a really simple function to apply a custom filter to an array of samples then this should do it... Just replace the logic in the loops in the capacitor() function with something more like the proper equations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INRADS *3.1416/180.0

#define NUM_SAMPLES 1000

double capVoltage = 0;
//this is a simple (capacitor like) filter.
int capacitor(double* sample, long samples, double capacitorValue, double totalTime, double initialCapVoltage){

    capVoltage = initialCapVoltage;

    for (int i = 0; i<= samples-1; i++){ //loop through all the samples
        if (sample[i] > capVoltage){ //charge the cap
            //put your math in here, calculate voltages based on capacitorValue, totalTime and capVoltage
            //this next line is just for testing purposes
            capVoltage += 0.2;
        }
        if (sample[i] < capVoltage){ //discharge the cap
            //put your math in here, calculate voltages based on capacitorValue, totalTime and capVoltage
            //this next line is just for testing purposes
            capVoltage -= 0.2;
        }
        sample[i] = capVoltage;
        printf("Changed sample %d to %f \n", i, sample[i]);
    }

}

double* myVoltageSamples; //generic wave sample
double* myVoltageSamples2; //generic wave sample

int main(){

    myVoltageSamples = new double[NUM_SAMPLES]; //let's say this is 1 sample every millisecond for one second
    myVoltageSamples2 = new double[NUM_SAMPLES]; //let's say this is 1 sample every millisecond for one second

    for (int i = 0; i<= NUM_SAMPLES-1; i++){ //put some data in the sample array
        myVoltageSamples[i] = sin( ( i ) INRADS );      // a simple, generic sin wave
        myVoltageSamples2[i] = myVoltageSamples[i];
        printf("Adding %f to the sample.\n", myVoltageSamples[i]);
    }
    //we now have a generic signal

    //apply your basic (capacitor) filter
    capacitor(myVoltageSamples2, NUM_SAMPLES, 0.001, 1000, 0); //1mF cap, one second, start voltage = 0

    //compare the start and finish:
    printf("first signal:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<= NUM_SAMPLES-1; i++){ //put some data in the sample array
        for (int j = 0; j<=((int)(myVoltageSamples[i]*20))+20-1; j++){
            printf(".");
        }
        printf("X\n");
    }

    printf("second signal:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<= NUM_SAMPLES-1; i++){ //put some data in the sample array
        for (int j = 0; j<=((int)(myVoltageSamples2[i]*20))+20-1; j++){
            printf(".");
        }
        printf("X\n");
    }

    delete myVoltageSamples;
    delete myVoltageSamples2;

}
```

Comment: The two loops at the bottom of the main function are just to provide a visual representation of the signals in the command line.